# Not a function Chrome console error

Tags: javascript

I've run this through JS Lint with 0 errors, but when I run the script in my Chrome console, it tells me that fil() is not a function. This pattern of closures has worked up until adding in the filter() function and I have no idea what's causing the break.

In the code below, calling index() works like it should but calling fil() returns an error.

```
"use strict";

function from(start) {
    return function () {
        var tempstart = start;
        start += 1;
        return tempstart;
    };
}

function to(gen, limit) {
    return function () {
        var localnum = gen();
        if (localnum < limit) {
            return localnum;
        }
        return undefined;
    };
}

function fromTo(start, end) {
    return to(from(start), end);
}

var index = fromTo(0, 3);
index();

function filter(gen, predicate) {
    var value;
    do {
        value = gen();
    } while (
        value !== undefined && !predicate(value)
    );
    return value;
}

var fil = filter(fromTo(0, 5), function third(value) {
    return (value % 3) === 0;
});

fil();
```

Comment: Because `filter` return a value not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to return a function with filter()... Added in a return for that and it's good.